# Text replacement in the middle of a line (linux command)

Tags: text-processing

```
/dev/mapper/vgsys0-xxxx /tmp ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec,rw 1 2
```

replace as below

```
/dev/xxxxx/xxxxx-xxxx /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2
```

Can you help me with search `/tmp` word and replace it with `/tmp ext4 nodev,nosuid,noexec,rw 1 2`,but the text before /tmp should not be changed  example  `/dev/mapper/vgsys0-lvtmp`  can be anything, just search with /tmp and prefix with `/tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to change the text after `/tmp`. You can use:

```
sed -E 's|([! ]*) /tmp.*$|\1 /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2|' file_name
```

e.g.

```
echo '/dev/mapper/vgsys0-xxxx /tmp' | sed -E 's|([! ]*) /tmp.*$|\1 /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2|'
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/vgsys0-xxxx /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2
```

```
echo '/dev/mapper/vgsys0-xxxx /tmp ext4 anyting,nosuid,noexec,rw 1 2' | sed -E 's|([! ]*) /tmp.*$|\1 /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2|'
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/vgsys0-xxxx /tmp ext4 defaults,rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Yadav, it worked

Comment: @Ramesh if it worked then please accept the answer (with the tick mark next to this answer). If you're particularly pleased with the answer then give it an up-vote too.

Comment: Done, thanks a lot